# Macro Filter for a Range of Values/ Numbers in excel using Command Button

Tags: excel, vba

I need support in creating a macro filter with command button.

I have numbers on column H2:H592

I would like to filter the values between a Range always. For examples 110 to 140

So I have two cells to enter the Range Excel F2 and F5.

I enter lower range as 110 and Upper Range as 140. I want the values between this range. I tried this by creating a command button macro and taking code for Automatic number filter from Record macro option. But doesnt work well. I mean not at all. Below is the code which used

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$H$5:$H$592").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=Range("F2")", _
        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=Range("125")"
```

Thanks in Prior

Comment: I think they may have a problem with `Criteria1:=">=Range("F2")", ` and `Criteria2:="<=Range("125")"`: Here quotes are understood by the machine like (replacing quotes by brackets) `Criteria1:= [Range(] F2 [)] ,`  instead of `Criteria1:= [Range( [F2] )] ,` as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the Ranges from the quotes otherwies they are treated  literally, and your second range was garbled.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$H$5:$H$592").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("F2"), _
        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Range("F5")
```

Including sheet references, amend to suit.

```
Sheets("Whatever").Range("$H$5:$H$592").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & Sheets("Whatever").Range("F2"), _
        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Sheets("Whatever").Range("F5")
```

Comment: Thanks SJR. It works well. Could you suggest online portals for knowing/learning these stuffs. I am a very beginner in excel-vba macros

Comment: My pleasure. Could you accept the answer please? I can't really recommend any particular site but if you google Excel VBA you will find a lot of useful tutorials and you can hang about websites like this.

Comment: Hallo SJR..! I am getting a RUN TIME ERROR:1004.  Autofilter Method of Range Class has failed.  this is the message I get

Comment: Opening the file in a different PC. That is the only thing happened. What does 'Active Sheet' mean..? Instead how can I mention the exact sheet reference instead of 'Active.Sheet'